# Hive SQL, find max count in sliding 10 minute window

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a table that is roughly (super simplified)

```
ts    | session | other_stuff
------------------------------
100   | A       | ...
101   | B       | ...
101   | A       | ...
102   | C       | ...
103   | A       | ...
104   | C       | ...
104   | A       | ...
9999  | D       | ...
20000 | D       | ...
```

`ts` is the timestamp stored as a double. I want to find the maximum number of active sessions in any 10 minute window. So in the example above the answer would be `3` because `A`, `B`, and `C` were all active within 10 minutes of each other. What is the right query for this, I've tried a couple of things but run into errors so I'm definitely not thinking about this the right way.

I attempted

```
SELECT  *,
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT session)
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.ts BETWEEN m.ts - 300 AND m.ts + 300
        ) AS maxconcurrent
FROM    mytable m
ORDER BY
    maxconcurrent DESC
```

but receive the error

```
Presto query has failed. Unexpected node: com.facebook.presto.sql.planner.plan.LateralJoinNode
```

Edit: Here's a table where the sliding nature of the window is important

```
ts    | session | other_stuff
------------------------------
100   | A       | ...
201   | B       | ...
301   | A       | ...
702   | C       | ...
1503  | A       | ...
2504  | C       | ...
3696  | A       | ...
9999  | D       | ...
20000 | D       | ...
```

The max is still 3 but now it's from the window that covers 201 to 801

Comment: if you did try..please include your attempts.

Comment: In the ts column what qualifies as a 10 min window?

Comment: @VK_217 it's timestamped in seconds so plus or minus 300 seconds is a 600 second (10 minute) window

Comment: In your 2nd set of data example the count cannot be 3. It is 2. Just A and B

Comment: @Bala `B @ 201` + `A @ 301` + `C @ 702` = 3 within 600 seconds of each other.

Comment: you are right.  It was an issue with my where condition. Amended it.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question.  Here is how I approached it

```
select * from sliding

+-------------+----------------+--+
| sliding.ts  | sliding.users  |
+-------------+----------------+--+
| 100         |  A             |
| 101         |  B             |
| 101         |  A             |
| 102         |  C             |
| 103         |  A             |
| 104         |  C             |
| 104         |  A             |
| 9999        |  D             |
| 20000       |  D             |
+-------------+----------------+--+
```

We now need to calculate the difference between `ts` of current row with `ts` of either previous row `(lag)` or the following row `(lead)`. `lag(ts,1,0)` comes handy it provides the `ts` of previous row. But there is a problem, what happens if the current row is the very first row?  No problem, use `lag(ts,1,0)` the `0` here is the default value returned if there are no previous rows.

Now all we need to do is to subtract value returned by `lag` from `ts` of current row and apply the condition (your time window). That is, check if current `ts - lag_ts` is within 600.

One might think that this would fail if the previous row's `ts` is much much higher than current row `ts`?  But it won't, because the `over` clause has `order by ts`.

```
select users, ts, lag, lead  from (
    select users, ts, 
         lag(ts,1,0) over (order by ts) as lag, 
         lead(ts,1) over( order by ts) as lead
    from sliding ) tbl
where (ts - lag) <= 600

+--------+------+------+-------+--+
| users  |  ts  | lag  | lead  |
+--------+------+------+-------+--+
|  A     | 100  | 0    | 101   |
|  A     | 101  | 100  | 101   |
|  B     | 101  | 101  | 102   |
|  C     | 102  | 101  | 103   |
|  A     | 103  | 102  | 104   |
|  A     | 104  | 103  | 104   |
|  C     | 104  | 104  | 9999  |
+--------+------+------+-------+--+
```

Applying distinct count gets

```
select count(distinct users)  from (
    select users, ts, 
         lag(ts,1,0) over (order by ts) as lag, 
         lead(ts,1) over( order by ts) as lead
    from sliding ) tbl
where (ts - lag) <= 600 


+------+--+
| _c0  |
+------+--+
| 3    |
+------+--+
```

Comment: This is certainly closer to the answer but I believe that this means that the window is a fixed with of 3 rows wide right?

Comment: I am not sure I have understood your question.  Please can you elaborate?

Comment: If I may guess, you want to know if the window is a fixed no. of 3 rows.  The answer is No.  It depends on the `time` window and the number of rows that satisfies the window condition (just like normal where clause).  Try increasing/reducing `300`, add few more rows with varying `ts`.

Comment: As you may be aware that It can be limited to 3 rows if required.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand `lag` and `lead` (this is very likely) let me give it a try.

Comment: I will add detailed explanations soon. I will check with other dataset too

Comment: Hmmm just ran it and got 67074 as the count, which definitely isn't right because I only have a couple hundred users :/

Comment: check the amended condition.  Let me know if it works!

Comment: Still getting something in the 67000 range

Comment: Unfortunately I wouldn't be able to comment on a data that I am unable to see :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not user if hive allows windowing to have dynamic bounding width, it only supports fixed windowing width as far as I understand

But see if this could work for you. use `floor` to round off nearest 10th minute timestamp and do a analytic function.

```
select  ts, session , count(distinct session) over (partition by floor((ts+599)/600) * 600) from your_table;
```

You result will look something like this:

```
ts    | session | cnt
------------------------------
100   | A       | 2
201   | B       | 2
301   | A       | 2
702   | C       | 1
```

`floor((ts+599)/600) * 600)` - this enables sessions with timestamp 0 - 600 will fall in one bucket, 601-1200 into another and so on.

Depending upon the hive version you use **distinct** part may/may not work in `count(distinct session) over (..)`